# How to include check multiple rows with array in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have three tables.

variants:

| id | title | item_id | model_number | part_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2579 | iPhone 11 (Purple, 64GB, Hong Kong) | 35 | A2223 | ZA/A |
| 2580 | iPhone 11 (Green, 64GB, Hong Kong) | 35 | A2223 | ZA/A |

attributes:

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | Japan | null |
| 23 | 64GB | null |

attributes_groups:

| id | variant_id(reference for table variants) | attribute_id(reference for table attributes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7475 | 2576 | 55 |
| 7476 | 2576 | 17 |
| 7477 | 2576 | 23 |

I want to retrieve the data using all the values in attributes and must include them in a way it doesn't get other data in attributes_groups.

```
const itemVariants = await db.variants.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.attributesGroups,
                    as: "attributes_groups",
                    required: true,
                    where:{
                        attribute_id:{
                            [db.Sequelize.Op.in]: atts
                        }
                    },
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.attributes,
                            as: "attribute",
                            required: true,
                            include:[
                                {
                                    attributes: ["id", "name"],
                                    model: db.attributes,
                                    as: "childs",
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
            where:{
                item_id: itemId,
                ...(modelNumberId? {model_number : modelNumberId}:{}),
                status_id: 1
            },

        });
```

for example I am passing:
attributes :  [57,17,23] itemId: "35"
I want to return variants that match all in the array in attributes array.

I tried Op.in in sequelize, and it didn't work.